# Jquery: Call then function when all nested ajax calls are also complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, nested, es6-promise, .when

I am trying to write some nested ajax calls with the help of function and when. But currently, my then function is not working as expected. I want to call then function when all Ajax calls are done including the nested ones. I want to call then function when

```
this.getDescendants(resourceId[1],resourceData.limit+resourceData.offset);
```

is also completed for all the main ajax calls. Currently, then is completing before the nested ajax calls are completing.

```
    getUserInfo: function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: UserURL,
            context: this,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              $('#fade-wrapper').fadeIn();
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic "+this._basicCred);
            },
            success: function(resourceData) {
                if(resourceData.resources != undefined && resourceData.resources.length > 0){
                    var deferreds = [];
                    for (var i=0; i < resourceData.resources.length; ++i){
                      var deferred = this.getDescendants(resourceData.resources[i],0);
                      deferreds.push(deferred);
                    }
                    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
                        var currentContext = this[0];
                        console.log(currentContext);
                        console.log("Then called.");
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("No visible resource has been found.");
                }
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error( status, err.toString());
                $('#fade-wrapper').fadeOut();
                alert("Error has occurred, please contact administrator in case the problem persists.");
                return null;
            }.bind(this)
        });
        
    },
    getDescendants: function(resId,offset){
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {"resId":resId},
            url: DesedentURL+"?limit=10&offset="+offset,
            context: this,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic "+this._basicCred);
            },
            success: function(resourceData, textStatus, xhr) {
                if(this._resResults == undefined){
                    this._resResults = [];
                }
                this._resResults.push(resourceData);
                console.log("resourceData");
                console.log(resourceData);
                if(resourceData.totalResults > (resourceData.limit+resourceData.offset) ){
                    var resourceId = resourceData.links[0].href.match("resources/(.*)/descendants");
                    console.log(resourceId);
                    this.getDescendants(resourceId[1],resourceData.limit+resourceData.offset);
                }
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error( status, err.toString());
                $('#fade-wrapper').fadeOut();
                alert("Error has occurred, please contact administrator in case the problem persists.");
                return null;
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
```

Comment: You may want to learn a bit more about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). A common pattern is to create an array of them and then pass that to Promise.all()

Comment: Hello Zmart, I tried to replicate the same. But the problem is that in my ajax I have to deal with some extra nested ajax calls based on the response. In extra ajax calls, I am facing the issue, as I don't aware when all extra nested ajax calls will complete.

Comment: Wrap them in a promise and have the promise resolve() inside the ajax call?